# Watsonx Assistant reconigze phone number from Twillio Integration

Tags: twilio, ibm-cloud, whatsapp, watson-assistant

I've developed a Whatspp chatbot using WatsonX Assistant and Twillio, using the official integration, however I cannot see a way to reference the user's cellphone number that sends a Whatsapp Message.

I'd expect this information to showup as a Integration Variable, but it's not showing there. I've verified that Twillio's Webhook is sending the phone number information, it just seems WatsonX Assistant does not store it.

Has anyone else had to deal with this issue before?

Tried searching on Twillio to see if there was a way to send the information creating a middleware
Tried checking the Twillio Integration configuration to see if I missed something.

Email both of their support channels to get clarification, Twillio confirms they are sending the information and IBM's Support didn't help.

Comment: Have you checked these variables? Are they empty? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-expression-integration-variables#expression-integration-variables-whatsapp

Comment: @data_henrik It worked! I thought the integration variable would show up if I connected, never occurred to me it was still being catalogued, just not showing in the web UI. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am posting it as answer, so that others can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone number is passed into watsonx Assistant as private variable. The section on the [WhatsApp integration and the data structure](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-expression-integration-variables#expression-integration-variables-whatsapp) has details.